# Hard vector inset shadow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, text, shadows, drop-shadow

I'm trying to re-create a hard inner shadow effect in illustrator, similar to the effect on the text in the Kit Kat logo:

[image]

Heres another good example:

[image]

Heres my attempt at re-creating it:

[image]

Mine seems like it needs some refinement, after a hours of trying this is the closest I could get and I'm still not quite happy with it. It seems like such a basic effect, but I think my brain is short circuiting.

Does anyone have a better technique to achieve this kind of effect? One of my main concerns is getting it to work across a variety of fonts.

Thanks!

Comment: There's really no way to get this to work "across a variety of fonts". Outside elements, sure, but not inside elements. It has to be manually altered for each font. Typefaces vary far too much to consistently create an appearance stack which will work for inner elements. Even a simple inset stroke often fails when fonts are changed.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you’re looking for?
[image]

This effect has been produced using Adobe® Illustrator® plugin called Oblique Projection 'opo’. I’ve written this extension to automate the creation process of parallel perspective effect (the inner shadow in your case). You can grab your free evaluation copy at http://63mutants.com/subc/products/opo_m01/opo_m01.php

And here is how to create the ‘KitKat’ effect using ‘opo’:

1)  create a new document (RGB color)

2)  create ‘shadow’ layer, and two sub-layers ‘mask’ and ‘text’:

[image]

3)  put your text on the ‘text’ layer (about 150pt height). Then select it and go to Object > Expand:

[image]

4)  select text and go to ‘opo’ panel, choose XY projection with 8px for X and -8px for Y (my text is about 90px height). Set projection order to ‘Z-‘ and projection type to ‘solid’. Choose ‘Custom Projection Color’ option and set fill to RGB 204,204,204. Hit ‘Create Projection’:

[image]

5)  this should produce:

[image]

6)  copy all objects from ‘text’ layer into ‘mask’ layer. Then toggle off visibility of ‘text’:

[image]

7)  select all objects from ‘mask’ layer and go to Object > Compound path > Make:

[image]

8)  go to Layers panel, select ‘shadow’ layer, and hit Make/Release Clipping Mask button:

[image]

[image]

9)  go to Layers panel, select all objects in ‘text_BZ-‘ layer and set its fill color to white:

[image]

10) create new ‘stroke’ layer (above ‘shadow’). Copy ‘text’ layer content into ‘stroke’ layer. Toggle of ‘text’ visibility:

[image]

11) select all objects in ‘stroke’, go to Objects > Ungroup and Objects > Compound path > Release

12) One more time Select all letters from the ‘stroke’ layer, go to Appearance Panel, hit Add New Stroke button. Set Stroke color to Brown, width to 8 px, align stroke to outside. One more time hit Add New Stroke button. Set Stroke color to White, width to 4 px, align stroke to outside:

[image]

Comment: You dont actually need the plugin offset will do. Shameless marketing :) it makes it easier tough.

Comment: yep. that's the point:). it makes it easier. and in the day-to-day professional design work time does matter.

Comment: Sure if you use it a lot scripting this took me 6 minutes. Its cheap nut also pointless :) On the other hand the newest post of the flat shadows there this is justified.

Comment: you are 100% right.

Comment: thats almost what im looking for, but i dont want to have to use a script or plugin. it looks like i could maybe accomplish the effect using a combination of the 3D tool and pathfinder.

Comment: if anyone has a better method keep those answers coming, im still trying to find the best way to do this. thanks everyone!